# Is this a Water Line?

Tags: pipe, gas, plumbing-fixture

My husband and I recently purchased a fridge that has an icemaker.  We thought this thing sticking out of our floor was a water line, but the installers said it was not.  When we inquired as to what it is, they said they didn't know.  We were hoping someone could tell us what this might be?[image]

Comment: I'd hook a hose to it and run it outside before opening the valve the first time.  Then let it run awhile to flush out the pipe.

Comment: In situations like this, look for a white limescale buildup around the joints and around the output. If you see this and / or corrosion it's a telltale sign that it's a water tap. The next question is, is it a cold water tap or a hot water tap?

Answer (score 1):

Appears to be a water valve with a hose bib connection.  Did you try to open the valve?  I would first locate the house main water shut off valve before you attempt to open the valve just in case the valve fails and floods you kitchen.
Try opening the valve and see if water comes out.  If it does, then I would shut off the house main water valve and replace this old valve with a new one.
Lowes or Home Depot sells the ice maker hookup kits that will connect to this type of water gate valve with the hose bib connector.

Comment: OMG!!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!  My husband said it is a water line.  We're in the process of redoing our kitchen and got our appliances today, although these things will have to be moved when we get the new floor (oh boy), but at least you told me something that I can actually use.  The company that installed it said they are resending someone out to check it.  Randall you are awesome.  Thank you.  I'll tell my hubby to get the things for it.

Comment: Yes you were helpful Randall.  Again, the installers are coming back out tomorrow.  I appreciate everyone's assistance.

Comment: @Jimmy Fix-it, this is the first time I've been to this site.  I was a bit bummed by what these installers mentioned to me and I was searching the web for helpful answers that could assist my family and I.  I'm not sure what your post has to do with what I was asking.  I would vote for both of the answers I received, however, this site tells me I can't vote for my own post.  So if you could offer up something useful in assisting with that process, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: No worries! If one of the other answers ends up being correct, just click the "accept" button on that answer. No big deal if you don't, welcome to the forum!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what it is but I would follow it downstairs and see what it's connected to!  That's the only sure way of knowing what it is.  Failing that, turn it on and see what comes out of it!

Comment: That's what we're going to do, but my husband swears it's a water line because before he purchased this property many years ago, he said a dishwasher was hooked to it, so I would assume water had to come from that pipe, but we are going to look into it.  The installers are coming back tomorrow to investigate it further.  I think they just didn't want to be bothered, but WE paid for them to install the fridge fully, so hopefully it will be tomorrow.  Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: If there was a dishwasher there, it might be a hot water line.  Is the shut-off valve red?  Kinda looks like it from the picture.

Comment: Yes, it's so dust filled, but it is red.  So what exactly does this mean that cold water wouldn't run through it?

Comment: Well if it's a hot water line, then it will be hooked into your hot water main (coming from your hot water tank) and hot water will come out of it after a warmup period.  Definitely do not want that going into your fridge!  Get a bucket and open it up and see what comes out.  As another poster suggested though, make sure you know how to shut off your hot water (there will be a valve or lever at the hot water tank) just in case the valve fails after having not been used in a while.

Comment: We will most definitely look into all of this.  I was trying to get an idea of what this pipe was.  I greatly appreciate your assistance and I'll definitely report back, once we find out what is going on with this valve.  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: I should also point out that refreigerator installation guys are not generally plumbers and will not be legally able to mess with your plumbing (other than screwing on a connector to a hose bib.  So it's unlikely they will be willing/able to switch this over to a cold water line.  The good news is though that it will likely be a pretty simple task for a homeowner as you probably have a cold water main running parallel to the hot water main that can be tapped in to.

Comment: You're right.  But the company that sold us this stuff should have also mentioned that to us as well.  They told us they would install and take care of everything we needed, but who knew, right?  But I get what you're saying though.  I just get tired of people so willing to take your money, but unwilling to help you have a viable solution to a problem.  Perhaps I'll call a plumber and see what can be done.  That is great news and thanks again for the tips.

Comment: Yeah I hear you and I agree it's unacceptable that they wouldn't have told you the terms of the agreement. Maybe they will pay for a plumber.  Best of luck with it!

Comment: That would be awesome, but somehow I doubt that's going to happen.  Can you tell me how I can vote up your helpful suggestions.  I've been accused of not be decent to you?  I have no idea how this site actually works.

Comment: I'm not sure! I just found this site yesterday to ask a question and I received a response so thought I would help someone else out.  Don't worry about the naysayers.

Comment: Ooh good, glad to hear that because this is my first time using it and was so thankful I got "real" responses.  Most of the time these so-called help forums aren't very helpful.  I really appreciate your help and the other poster.  At least I know I have something to go on when I talk to the company tomorrow.  It was more than I had.  Thank you, you've been quite nice and it's refreshing to see that on the web.  Most of the time, it's just the opposite.  Take care!

Comment: By the way - if you decide to tap the cold water line yourself - here's  a great video showing a few options.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d4X1yg-Fb88

Comment: My husband and I have contacted a plumber who is going to fix the water line.  You guys were right, it is definitely a water line, and it was used to dispense hot water.  So he's changing it over to cold and has the kit to hook up our icemaker.  I really cannot thank you both enough.  I was having a rough day, and I was so thankful to find this site and have someone answer my questions.  You both were great, and thanks so much for your expertise!